# Use a SP to Archive/Revision related records in several related tables?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, archive

I have a database for an application that has a complicated relational table structure. Is there a good way to create revisions of the data, or archive the data before a user makes changes?

Ideally I would want a stored procedure that would save the state of all the related data when ran, insomuch that when a field is added to any of the related tables, the stored procedure would not miss it.

Comment: Are you talking about structural changes to your database as in DDL changes? Or are you talking about a user updating a particular row, DML?

Comment: Are you thinking of implementing a temporal database, where each value has a datetime range when it is the effective value, and all past values are also retained?

Answer (score 2):

Creating such a stored procedure is probably going to be complex and error prone. That's why there are temporal databases or temporal features in a database. If you really wanted to do this with a stored procedure, you can have a duplicate schema with a version number column added to all tables.

That way, on each write operation, you can first call the stored procedure which does an `INSERT INTO.... SELECT` using the same `WHERE` clause as your write operation. The stored procedure is best initiated by the app which runs the stored procedure before the actual write (UPDATE/DELETE) statement.

If you use triggers, it can be very tricky just figuring out which table(s) to host the trigger and making sure you don't get a trigger storm.

Far easier path is to implement something like Temporal tables in SQL Server 2016: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn935015.aspx. Takes a bit of work to setup but it's only somewhat tedious work, not very complex work. If you want to keep this history around for a long time, you can even stretch the temporal history table so you don't have to deal with administration and storage challenges with a massive history table.